# How to enable Async support for Sling Servlet - Felix

Tags: osgi, aem, apache-felix, sling

I have this code

```
  @Component(service = Servlet.class, scope = ServiceScope.PROTOTYPE, property={
    HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_SERVLET_PATTERN+"=/content/*",
    HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_FILTER_ASYNC_SUPPORTED+"=true",
    HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_SERVLET_ASYNC_SUPPORTED+"=true"}
    )
  @SlingServletResourceTypes(
    resourceTypes="cq/Page",
    methods=HttpConstants.METHOD_GET,
    selectors = "asynctest",
    extensions="json")
   public class ReactiveServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(
        HttpServletRequest  request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
         AsyncContext async = request.startAsync();
        // Some logic
        }
 }
```

When calling this servlet /content/mypage.asynctest.json then getting this error

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: null
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:338) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:369) [org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api:1.1.2]
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:369) [org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api:1.1.2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that **async is NOT supported** by Sling-Servlets. Your exception is thrown in this class:

https://github.com/apache/felix-dev/blob/master/http/base/src/main/java/org/apache/felix/http/base/internal/dispatch/ServletRequestWrapper.java

```
@Override
public AsyncContext startAsync() throws IllegalStateException
{
    if ( !this.asyncSupported )
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    return super.startAsync();
}
```

But you are mixing OSGi Http-Whiteboard Pattern with Sling-Servlets. I'm not sure, what you wanted to do.

Sling/AEM is a technology-stack, where layer is built on layer. Unfortunately multiple of these layers allow registering a servlet.

- **Sling Servlets** = Apache Sling (recommended, default)
- **OSGi HTTP Whiteboard Pattern** = Apache Felix (only for special cases)
- **JEE Servlet** = Jetty Servlet Container (NOT recommended)

---

**Sling-Servlet**

The Sling-Servlet you registered with `@SlingServletResourceTypes` **doesn't support async**. The output of the following servlet is: `Async is not supported by an Sling-Servlet!` (http://localhost:4502/content/we-retail.asynctest.json)

```
import static org.apache.sling.api.servlets.ServletResolverConstants.*;

import javax.servlet.AsyncContext;
import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;

@Component(service = Servlet.class, property = {
        SLING_SERVLET_RESOURCE_TYPES + "=cq:Page",
        SLING_SERVLET_SELECTORS + "=asynctest",
        SLING_SERVLET_EXTENSIONS + "=json",
        SLING_SERVLET_METHODS + "=GET"
})
public class AsyncSlingServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(
            SlingHttpServletRequest request,
            SlingHttpServletResponse response
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {

        if (request.isAsyncSupported() /* false */) {
            final AsyncContext async = request.startAsync();
            async.start(() -> {
                async.getResponse().setContentType("text/plain");
                async.getResponse().setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
                try {
                    async.getResponse().getWriter().println(
                            "Hello from the Sling-Servlet!");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // ignore
                }
                async.complete();
            });
        } else {
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
            response.getWriter().println(
                    "Async is not supported by an Sling-Servlet!");
        }
    }
}
```

---

**OSGi HTTP Whiteboard Pattern**

The almost same servlet registered via the OSGi HTTP Whiteboard pattern **supports async**. It returns `Hello from the OSGi Http-Whiteboard Servlet!` (http://localhost:4502/my-project/hello). But such servlets are aside to Sling, so they are "rivals" or "competitors". You have to be careful, not to negatively impact Sling. So the /content path should be avoided.

```
import javax.servlet.AsyncContext;
import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.ServiceScope;
import org.osgi.service.http.whiteboard.HttpWhiteboardConstants;

@Component(
        service = Servlet.class,
        scope = ServiceScope.PROTOTYPE,
        property = {
                HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_SERVLET_PATTERN
                        + "=/my-project/*",
                HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_CONTEXT_SELECT
                        + "=("
                        + HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_CONTEXT_NAME
                        + "=org.apache.sling)",
                HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_FILTER_ASYNC_SUPPORTED
                        + "=true",
                HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_SERVLET_ASYNC_SUPPORTED
                        + "=true" }
)
public class AsyncOSGiServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        if (request.isAsyncSupported() /* true */) {
            final AsyncContext async = request.startAsync();
            async.start(() -> {
                async.getResponse().setContentType("text/plain");
                async.getResponse().setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
                try {
                    async.getResponse().getWriter().println(
                            "Hello from the OSGi Http-Whiteboard Servlet!");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // ignore
                }
                async.complete();
            });
        } else {
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
            response.getWriter().println(
                    "Async is not supported by an OSGi Http-Whiteboard Servlet!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation, do you have an idea why Sling servlet does not support this? I guess this could be because JCR Session is not thread safe?

Comment: The JCR Session is a good point. But probably even Sling cannot handle it. Actually most other HTTP frameworks also don't support async. Before a sling-servlet is called, the Sling-Framework already does a lot processing with the request. It resolves the resource, applies many request-filters, renders it, applies many response-filters and post-process it (e.g. link-rewriter). This is all NOT implemented for async. Async only makes sense, if the above framework could free most of  the blocked resources. But Sling just waits for the rendering - and the entire thread is blocked.

Comment: BUT: You can just increase the number of Sling threads, if you need. Java is not JavaScript. Only in JS you must use async, because JS is single-threaded.

Comment: BUT NOT: In Java you have some costs with long-running threads. There are good reasons to avoid them. But in JS they are deadly. In Java they have a slight performance impact.

Comment: Thanks again, as Jetty container supports the Reactive nature of programming, so I was thinking that using Sling could be possible. Increasing Sling threads is an option but this approach does not match with the Ractive pattern.

Comment: Jetty has support for all of what you describe, even when using Servlet async processing APIs or Servlet async I/O APIs, check out the HttpInput and HttpOutput Interceptors for how to handle the sling filters and rendering layers in a way that works for both blocking and async servlet api usage.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt, would you pls suggest some examples, a google search does not show meaningful results?